# Unplugged USB stick while formatting - now not recognized any more

Tags: usb, format

I was formatting my USB memory stick using Ubuntu and chose "Override existing data".

I accidentally knocked the memory stick out of the USB port. When I put it back into my Ubuntu computer it was not visible in the file manager (Nautilus), and it does not appear in my unity dock.

I have already tried rebooting the computer with the memory stick inserted. But no effect.

What can I do to bring my memory stick back to life?

Comment: it does not appear in  `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: You can format it again using `Disks` or `gparted`.

Comment: Does it appear in `lsblk` and `lsusb`? What about `sudo parted -l` (needs admin password)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is most likely a hardware problem

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Launch GParted from the dash, switch to the usb stick, choose `Device → Create Partition Table` (accept the default setting), create a new partition.

Comment: So what if it's not visible in GParted?

Comment: Then it seems a lot like a hardware defect. (Especially since you added that it doesn't show up in `sudo fdisk -l`.)

Comment: Ah sorry I am not the OP and I realized, that my device does show up, only had to select `sdb` on the top right corner in `GParted` : )